# How to get date and time from timezone in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function getDate()
{
    $date='';
    $timezone = "Asia/Kolkata";
    if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $date=date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    return $date;
}

public function submitClient() 
{
   $date=$this->util_model->getDate();
   print($date);
}
```

I have made a function getDate() for getting date and time from timezone and called that function into submitClient() but i am getting system date and time not getting current date and time of Asian/Kolkata timezone so how to get that date and time??

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
$datestring = "Year: %Y Month: %m Day: %d - %h:%i %a";
$time = time();

echo mdate($datestring, $time);
```

it is too easy rather then create a function.

i hope it will work for you.

Comment: ok...but i want timezome date if my system or machine date is wrong then how to get exact date ??